# Save array of strings in an excel table using python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7

I have a list of persons , each person is represented with array of strings:

```
person1=["amy","fisher",34,"teacher"]
person2=["john","wayne",45,"astronaut"]
```

I want to save the list of persons in an excel table and have as a header :

```
name family_name   age  profession
amy  fisher        34   teacher
```

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: I managed to get another example work with numpy but in that example I used only integers .I can show you the code if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
person1=["amy","fisher",34,"teacher"]
person2=["john","wayne",45,"astronaut"]
#construct a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','family_name','age','profession'], data=[person1,person2])
#write it to an excel file
df.to_excel('output.xls',index=False)
```

Comment: But ,if I have 1000 persons, how should i modify the code?

Comment: How are your 1000 persons stored? Are they in a list or a file something else?

Comment: actually they are in a list

Comment: what's the format of the list? Does it look like this [["amy","fisher",34,"teacher"],["john","wayne",45,"astronaut"]]?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like that

Comment: Can you show me how you are going to do it in a loop?

Comment: Then that's easy, you just do something like: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','family_name','age','profession'], data=your_1000_person_list)

Comment: No worries. Please accept it as your answer if it helps.

Comment: one last thing , I'm using webservice and I have server send me 1 line at a time.how should I build my table line by line?

Comment: this will append a new person to your dataframe: df.loc[len(df)] = your_new_person_list

Comment: Thanks a lot Allen

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) library, you can install it using `pip install xlwt`.

```
import xlwt

headers = ['name', 'family_name', 'age', 'profession']
persons = [["amy", "fisher", 34, "teacher"],
           ["john", "wayne", 45, "astronaut"]]

# font style
style0 = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index black, bold on')

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')

# write headers
for index, value in enumerate(headers):
    ws.write(0, index, value, style0)

# write data
for row, person in enumerate(persons):
    for index, value in enumerate(person):
        ws.write(row+1, index, value)       

wb.save('persons.xls')
```

This will create the excel file you want.